How to calculate request response time in struts interceptor and store mdc
I use spring mvc, struts2, log4j. I use the following code:
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;
public class RequestTimerInterceptor extends BaseInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Long> REQUEST_DURATION = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final String DURATION_KEY = "processingTime";
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String, String> copyOfContextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    String result;
    try {
        result = invocation.invoke();
    } finally {
        try {
            MDC.setContextMap(copyOfContextMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long processingTime = endTime - startTime;
        REQUEST_DURATION.set(processingTime);
        MDC.put(DURATION_KEY, Long.toString(processingTime));           
    }
        return result;
   }
}

After the result = invocation.invoke(); line, the response time stored in the MDC is not visible in the log that is json in file. without using logback.
I am trying to calculate how long it takes to respond to a request and save it to the log as json. log4j
I tried to save the MDC before invocation.invoke()  and set it again after this line, but it didn't work.
Thank you for your guidance:)

The MDC.put() call is correct. Obviously the additional entry will be available only to log events that happen after the action was called. Can you provide examples of log statements that you expect to have the processingTime entry?

{"@timestamp":"2024-08-11T07:05:35.865Z","app_id":"SABA","level":"DEBUG","RequestMethod":"POST","RequestURI":"https://localhost:8443/common/get-notification.ib","StatusCode":"200","UserId":"otptU20000", "processingTime": "230ms}.

I want to calculate how long it takes to send a request and receive a response

log4j :%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %-30.30c{2}-[%X{RequestMethod}|%X{processingTime}]-%m%n%throwable{full}

%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %-30.30c{2}-[%X{RequestMethod}|%X{processingTime}]-%m%n%throwable{full}

Instead of adding the value to the MDC you should log the various elements as a MapMessage.

please give me an example

Your code doesn't contain a log statement, so you are relying on other interceptors and filters to do the actual logging.
Instead of that you can do the logging yourself in your interceptor, with a code like this one:
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final ActionContext actionContext = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
    final ServletContext servletContext = actionContext.getServletContext();
    final HttpServletRequest request = actionContext.getServletRequest();
    try {
         return actionInvocation.invoke();
    } finally {
        logger.debug(() -> new StringMapMessage()
                .with("app_id", servletContext.getServletContextName())
                .with("RequestMethod", request.getMethod())
                .with("RequestUri", request.getRequestURI())
                .with("processingTime", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
}

To obtain an output as in your comment above:
{"@timestamp":"2024-08-11T07:05:35.865Z","app_id":"SABA","level":"DEBUG","RequestMethod":"POST","RequestURI":"localhost:8443/common/…", "processingTime": "230ms}

use a JSON Template Layout with a map resolver:
<JsonTemplateLayout>
  <EventTemplateAdditionalField key="message" 
                                format="JSON" 
                                value='{"$resolver":"map","flatten":true}'/>
</JsonTemplateLayout>

Remark: In the code above I am using the following Log4j API imports:
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.StringMapMessage;

